# jQuery: How do I make an ajax call to backend and not submit form on button click?

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rDe9V/

**Steps to reproduce :**

1. Enter in textbox
2. Click "Add to playlist" and add some text in textbox
3. Click "New"

The alert box doesn't seem to work. The relevant jQuery function is here

```
$(function() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0)
    });
    $('form .create-playlist-button').click(function(e) {
        var title = $(e.target).closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
        alert(title);
    });
});
```

Please help in understanding why this is not working.

---

**UPDATE**

SO doesn't allows to ask more that 6 question/day. so I am updating here

I made the change to fiddle, its here now -- http://jsfiddle.net/rDe9V/2/

```
   $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0).click(function(e){
            var title = $(e.target).closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
            alert(title);
        });
    });
```

**Needed**

- On button click, should not POST form

---

Comment: Quite a few errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The "New" button is submitting a form.

You have to kill the event of submitting that form, or else it will be submitted and your page will refresh itself, posting (or getting) with the form data.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that, Please see the update, about what my requirement is, may be you have a fair idea of how to achieve this, please advice

Comment: @daydreamer make a new question. SO is **not** a debugging service. you cannot just keep updating your question with new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your click event isn't registering, and you should define your button as a button instead of submit.

```
var clickAdded = false;

// creating new playlist
$(function() {
        $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
            var val = $.trim(this.value);
            $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0);
            if (val.length > 0 && !clickAdded) {
                $('form .create-playlist-button').click(function(e){
                     var title = $(e.target).closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
                     alert(title); return false;
                 });
                clickAdded = true;
            }

        });});
```